# jquery sortable validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery validation in order to sort banners on a website.

I have three types of banners:

- Default Banner (set by the company, existing rule cannot be removed but can be sorted)
- Selectable Banner (selectable banner form a list of many)
- Special Banner (special banner, set by the company difference between this and default is that they can be removed from the carousel)

The banners carousel has a few rules no more than 7 banners are allowed into the carousel and four of these can be custom, with the four of these being selectablebanners. I've got the logic for this as follows:

```
 // no more than 7 banners allowed 
   $("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    //receive: This event is triggered when a connected sortable list has received an item from another list.
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        // so if > 7
        if ($(this).children().length > 7) {
            //ui.sender: will cancel the change. Useful in the 'receive' callback.
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            alert('Your selection has been cancelled. A maximum 7 banners are allowed in the carousel.');
        }
        if ( $('#sortable1 .selectablebanner').length > 4) {
            alert('Your selection has been cancelled. A maximum 4 custom banners are allowed in the carousel.');
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        }  
    }
}).disableSelection();
});
```

Another rule I have in place is that a default banner cannot be removed but it can be sorted. I've implemented this as so:

```
$("#sortable2").sortable({
cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
  receive: function (event, ui) {
       if (ui.item.hasClass("defaultbanner")) {
           $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
           alert("This is a default banner, it can be sorted but not removed.");
       }
   }
```

});

However I would like to amend this slightly but have no idea how to begin with this logic as it is slightly more advanced.

The rule I want to implement is that if there are 2 or more "selectedbanners" in ul#sortable1 then the default banners can be removed. However if only for example there is a single defaultbanner and a single selectablebanner. Then I would like my previous validation to apply which is that a default banner cannot be removed.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/7HTMz/1/) which has my full code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Special Banner
Selectable Banner
Special Banner" - isn't first and third the same..? "and four of these can be custom" , "a default banner" - what is a custom banner and what is a default banner..?

Comment: Can you explain why you're initializing everything multiple times in that fiddle..?

Comment: sorry mate @TilwinJoy should  have been special banner, selectable banner, default banner. default is set by company, special banner can be removed but is set by company. selectable is selectable by the client

Comment: @TilwinJoy do you understand now? The rule that I require is that if #sortable has more than 2 selectablebanners (which is in the class of each banner that is selectable) then they can be removed from this list. However if there is less than 2 then the defaultbanners can be sorted but not removed

Comment: yes, now i'm getting some of it. can you add the rules one by one as a bulleted list in question so that it's easier to understand..? btw for setting each rule you're reinitializing the sortable with new set of options, so you're losing the previously set rules… you need to add all the condition checking in one initialization. also applying different colors for different banners will be a good idea for better understandability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me, however this is my best guess as to what you might be looking for.

```
$("#sortable2").sortable({
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
      receive: function (event, ui) {
           if (ui.item.hasClass("defaultbanner") && $('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
               $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
               alert("This is a default banner, it can be sorted but not removed.");
           }
           else if($('#sortable1 li').length <= 1) {
              $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
              alert('You must have at least two banners');    
          }
       }
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ZFF/)

Comment: Any particular reason for initializing everything two times..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy No, the initialization of sortables could definitely be consolidated..  And actually It looks like `.sortable` is being initialized three times for each #sortable